# Property 'arrayBuffer' does not exist on type 'File'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting a type error while implementing code for file upload in Angular application. I am using angular 8 and typescript 3.5.3. Following is my code

Template
`<input type="file" id="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">`

And function in component class

```
  handleFileInput(files: FileList): void {
    files[0].arrayBuffer().then((value) => {
      console.log(value);
    });
   }
```

While compiling I get this error:
`error TS2339: Property 'arrayBuffer' does not exist on type 'File'.`

Any idea how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2):

This error appears, because The `arrayBuffer()`, `stream()`, and `text()` are actually missing from the type definition of `File` / `Blob`. This is not an overlook though, according to the MDN these methods are still only part of a Working Draft and not well supported. If you want to patch the typing, to be still able to use the features like arrayBuffer() without typescript complaining, then you can extend the `File` interface with a missing property, i.e.:

```js
File {
    arrayBuffer: () => Promise<ArrayBuffer>
}
```

For reference see: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34652

Comment: size:number         // 116819
  type: string,       // 'image/jpeg'
  name: string,       // 'WhatsApp Image 2023-06-13 at 3.59.22 PM.jpg'
  lastModified:number // 1692654583776
can be added besides arrayBuffer

Answer (score -1):

Change your code html to

```
<input type="file" id="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event)">
```

Your TS

```
handleFileInput(event: Event) {
   const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
   const reader = new FileReader();
   let preview;
   reader.onload = () => {
     this.preview = reader.result as string;
   };
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Comment: There's a method `arrayBuffer` on `File` type with `typescript`, he was asking about it.